# AzureFiles access denied Linux

Tags: java, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-appservice, azure-files

I'm stuck with a problem of file access in my virtual machine.
I actually have two app services (linux) with a mounting point to the AzureFiles. This actually works but I'm trying to put one of the app on a virtual machine (ubuntu 20).

I can connect the AzureFiles using the provided script by Azure with the protocol SMB. But I have got some errors using my apps (Java):

| AccessDeniedException | NoSuchFileException |
| --- | --- |
| Files.move() | // for f in directory `Files.delete(f)` |
| Files are mount with 777 with nogroup nobody on the app service app, and 777 root root on the azure vm | Files are correctly detected by the for loop, but nosuchfile is thrown by delete. |

Here are the mounting points :

App service :
`//mystorage.file.core.windows.net/mypath /mypath cifs rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict,username=myusername,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=x.x.x.x,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,soft,persistenthandles,nounix,serverino,mapposix,mfsymlinks,noperm,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1 0 0`

VM:
`//mystorage.file.core.windows.net/mypath /mypath cifs nofail,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/mystorage.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino,nosharesock,actimeo=30`

EDIT : It seems to be stuck only with files created by the application on the VM. If I upload a file with Azure Strorage explorer, the delete function works.

Any idea why it doesn't work ?
Thanks

Comment: It was a SMB performance issue, adjusting echo_interval=60,actimeo=1 solves the problem.

Comment: Can u post the above comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a SMB performance issue, adjusting echo_interval=60,actimeo=1 solves the problem.